# How to find only one word after a pattern with spaces?

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, grep

I want to get only the number between the equal sign and eV

```
Final energy =  -2959.123199674     eV
```

I cannot just grep the equal symbol because there are too many of them in this file. I want to grep "Final energy =" and obtain back -2959.123199674.

I tried:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="Final Energy =")print $(i+1)}' filename
```

But it doesn't work

How can I include those blank spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed` like

```
sed -n 's/.*Final [Ee]nergy *= *\([0-9.-]*\).*/\1/p' filename
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/xPx6ar):

```
s="Final energy =  -2959.123199674     eV"
sed -n 's/.*Final [Ee]nergy *= *\([0-9.-]*\).*/\1/p'  <<< "$s"
# => -2959.123199674
```

The `.*Final [Ee]nergy *= *\([0-9.-]*\).*` POSIX BRE pattern will match the whole line that has `Final energy` (I used a bracket expression to match `e` or `E`), zero or more spaces, `=`, again zero or more spaces, and then will capture into Group 1 (`\1`) any 0 or more digits, dots or hyphens. The `-n` and `p` options will make `sed` only print the substitution result.

If you prefer to capture any chars other than whitespace into Group 1, replace `[0-9.-]*` with `[^[:space:]]*`. Or even `[^ ]*`.

Comment: Do you know how I can match a line that starts with "*  x" instead of "Final energy ="? The star symbol might be a problem?

Comment: @Caterina No problem, use `/^\* x/` to match `* x` substring at the start of  a line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '{sub(/.*=/,"");sub(/eV.*/,"");gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

First grep for `Final energy`, then use `grep -o` to extract the number:

```
grep 'Final energy =' | grep -o '[-[:digit:].]*'
```